# Magmi import products

Tags: magmi

I have a problem with media gallery import.

In my csv file I use

image
small_image

sku;image;small_image

In website http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

/extraimg1.jpg;/extraimg2.jpg

If I create gallery images I need to create a new field?

sku;image;small_image;gallery_image
001;0001.jpg;0000_2.jpg;0000_3.jpg;/000_4.jpg
or
sku;image;small_image;gallery_image
001;0001.jpg;0000_2.jpg;0000_3.jpg,/000_4.jpg
or
sku;image;small_image;gallery_image
001;0001.jpg;0000_2.jpg;0000_3.jpg,000_4.jpg

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki you have to add a new field named "media_gallery".

**Example:** /extraimg1.jpg;/extraimg2.jpg

Also, for your convenience, you can use the Column Mapper plugin to merge the fields "image", "small_image" and "thumbnail", resulting in an easier maintainable CSV file.